# How to Get PowerShell Core to Count Files in OneDrive Sync Directories, Recursively?

Tags: powershell, onedrive

I tried to use the following command in PowerShell Core (v6.2.2) on a OneDrive sync directory but it would only return the counts for the directories in the root directory. It worked fine in other directories outside of the OneDrive sync folder.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | %{ "$($_.FullName) $((gci $_.FullName).Count)" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to use the `-FollowSymlink` parameter.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -FollowSymlink | %{ "$($_.FullName) $((gci $_.FullName).Count)" }
```

I found the following pull request to helped to answer the question.
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/9509